# Access Environment based application.properties file in class not managed by spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, java-8

I am working on spring boot project having version 2.1.6.RELEASE and xslt 1.0.

I have a class that has a set of static methods used to generate the set of URL's using custom logic related to the application.

```
public class URLGenerator{

    public static String generateURLA(String param1,String param2,String param3)
    {
        String restServiceUrl=<acess url from application.properties>
        //code to invoke third party service
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        String url=restTemplate.invoke()
        return url;
    }
}
```

In the above method, I have to make a rest call to third party service to retrieve the final URL. The URL to invoke the service is different for every environment so I have stored the URL inside the application-{env}.properties file.

I will not be able to change the above method to non static as there are several xsl files invoke the above method.

What is the best way to access the environment based application.properties file in class which is not managed by Spring?

Comment: Why, in a spring managed application, would you have such things? And, perhaps more importantly, why would you be created a rest template every time?! You’re losing all the autoconfiguration benefits _and_ writing untestable code. Throw away this utility class!

Comment: @Boris. I cant throw away that utility class just like that. The methods inside the utility class are all static and they are invoked from several xslt's directly. So I can't make them non static as well. Is it possible to create a spring bean with all static method and autowire the property ? If yes can you share me example. Thanks.

Comment: Anything is of course possible. But Spring supports XSLT as a view technology - it sounds like you’re rolling your own and trying to use spring. This seems to me to be more and more of an XY problem. Is the real question “how do I access spring beans for a XSLT view?”?

Comment: @Boris. No that is not the question. I am using xslt to generate some xml file which I later FTP to target server. One of the element in xslt requires a URL to be generated and for that I have to invoke the utility class which invokes the third party service to generate it. The problem is should I make the utility class containing the set of static methods managed by spring? If yes how to do that and if not how to get enviroment specific property accessible to non managed spring class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply autowire `Environment` and get the property:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

public void method() {
    String url = env.getProperty("service.url");
    // ...
}
```

If it's not a bean, you can simply create a service, that does that:

```
@Service
class PropertyService implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private static PropertyService instance;

    public void method() {
        String url = env.getProperty("service.url");
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static PropertyService get() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. But I have the utility class which contains set of static methods and I cant make them non static. so is there way to create a bean with all static methods and is it a good idea?

Comment: @Beast check out my edit. This will allow to access the service by using `get` method.

Comment: In my case the method public void method() is a static method. So I will get an error that can not make static reference to non static field as I am trying to access environment variable from it. I cant make public void method() non static as  it is getting directly invoked from xslt1.0.

Comment: @Beast that's why the static accessor... Why can't you call `PropertyService ps = PropertyService.get();` in your static class? And then `ps.method()`...

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain old properties here.

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("/path/application.properties"));
props.getProperty("urls.foo"));
props.getProperty("urls.bar"));
```

OR

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
  props.load(is);
  props.getProperty("urls.foo"));
  props.getProperty("urls.bar"));
}
```